# Issue with Horizontal Layout in React Carousel Using Ant Design and CSS Flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

```
  

  import React from 'react'  
 import { Carousel,Input,Button ,Grid, Row} from 'antd'
import girl from "../sliderImages/girl1.png"
function SliderCarousel() {
    return (
 <div className='CarouselContainer'>   
       <Carousel className='Carousel'>
    
          <div className='Slider'>
               
                    <div className='ImageDiv'>

                        <img 
                        className='img'
                        src={girl}
                        alt='men'
                        >
                        </img>
                    </div> 
                 
                    <div className='content'>
                        <p style={{color:"black"}}>content my </p>
                        
                    </div>
               
          </div>
       </Carousel>
 </div>
</div>     
    )
}

export default Slider Carousel



using CSS:

  .Carousel{
     width:100%;
     
     
    height: 86vh;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    
  }

  .Slider{
 
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      width: 100%;
      
    
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center; 
   

  }

  .ImageDiv {
    flex: 1;
    width: 55vh; 
    height: 100%; 
  
     
    
     
  }
   .img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    
   }

  .content {
  

    flex: 1; 
    
    width: 48%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    float: right;
    display: flex;
  
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: blue;
   
    justify-content: flex-end;

  }
```

Expected Behavior:
I expect the image and content description to be displayed in a horizontal layout within each carousel slide.

Actual Behavior:
The image and content description are stacking vertically instead of being displayed side by side.

What I've Tried:

I have used the CSS Flexbox layout to create a horizontal layout.
I have adjusted the width of the image and content description divs.